# How do I dynamically calculate the right RGB colour to contrast with a background colour?

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, rgb

I´m trying to understand how I would recreate the functionality here where the colour of the text changes as hte background colour changes - such that the colour is consistantly visble :

http://colourco.de/

Answer (score 0):

This is HSL implementation, with fixed Saturation = 50%

X-axis changes Hue value from 0-359

Y-axis changes luminosity from 0%-100%